# How to create .so (Shared Object library file) from .c (C file) for Arm Processor?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I wanted to create a Prebuilt Shared library **.so** from **.c** file for **ARM** processor. Kindly give me some steps to do this and also how to include and access its functions in android.

Comment: The topic is too big for a single StackOverflow answer. Read this instead: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/ If stuck on a particular point, feel free to ask more questions here.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for:

```
LOCAL_PATH       := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE     := my_static_lib
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := src
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := src/main_main.c
# Use this one to build a *.a file - static library
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY) 
# Use this one to build a *.so file - a shared library
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: How `my_static_lib` is an .so ?